# does GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT require glInvalidateBufferSubData?

Tags: opengl

This may be an odd question, but either I didn't see it or it isn't noted.

I am using

`glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, BufferSize, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT`)

The docs state:

> GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT indicates that the previous contents of
>   the specified range may be discarded. Data within this range are
>   undefined with the exception of subsequently written data. No GL error
>   is generated if subsequent GL operations access unwritten data, but
>   the result is undefined and system errors (possibly including program
>   termination) may occur. This flag may not be used in combination with
>   GL_MAP_READ_BIT.

Now, this doesn't reveal to me if it does it now automatically (which I doubt) or if this requires some manual trigger like glInvalidateBufferSubData?

I can't see any performance difference either way, so I am a bit curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of that bit makes the mapping call *cause* invalidation, not suggest it ;)

However, if you're using persistent mapping, there's really no point in specifying that bit. You're only going to map the buffer once, as that's kinda the point of using persistent mapping. And invalidating a persistent mapped buffer, while legal, will probably not actually do anything.